# Solve a nonlinear ode system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

I want to solve the system:$$\begin{align}
\dfrac{dx}{dt}&= -y \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \\ \\  \dfrac{dy}{dt}&= x \sqrt{x^2+y^2}
\end{align}$$I basically have no idea about how to solve this since this system is not linear. At first glance, I saw $x^2+y^2$, so I think probably I have to use polar coordinate transformation, but I don't know how to do this.
$x,y$ are two functions depends on $t$ ,  if I directly let $x=r \cos \theta$ and $y= r \sin \theta$ ,  I don't think this makes sence. Any help on this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do polar coordinates, we can use

$$r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \implies \frac{dr}{dt} = \cos\theta\frac{dx}{dt} + \sin\theta\frac{dy}{dt}$$

$$\theta = \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right) + C \implies \frac{d\theta}{dt} = -\frac{\sin\theta}{r}\frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{\cos\theta}{r}\frac{dy}{dt}$$

by the chain rule. It's useful to keep those derivative relationships in mind, and an easy mnemonic to remember it is that the coefficients are exactly the rotation matrix that rotates a vector by $\theta$

$$\begin{pmatrix}\frac{dr}{dt} \\ r\frac{d\theta}{dt}\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta & \sin\theta \\ -\sin\theta & \cos\theta\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\frac{dx}{dt} \\ \frac{dy}{dt}\end{pmatrix}$$

Plugging the original system into this change of variables, we obtain

$$\begin{cases}\frac{dr}{dt} = 0 \\ \frac{d\theta}{dt} = r\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 3):

$$\dfrac{dx}{dt}= -y \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \\ \\  \dfrac{dy}{dt}= x \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$
$$x\dfrac{dx}{dt}= -xy \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \\ \\  y\dfrac{dy}{dt}= xy \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$
Add both DE and integrate:
$$x\dfrac{dx}{dt}+y \dfrac{dy}{dt}=0$$
$$x^2+y^2=C$$
You can use this to solve any of the original DE.
And yes you can also use polar coordinates to solve the system.

Comment: I'm pretty interested in how should I use polar coordinates to solve the problem that I posted. Can you also show this method or tell me where can I find a detailed description of it?

Comment: Also, I what to make sure that when you get $x \frac{dx}{dt}+y \frac{dy}{dt}=0$, you solve this by times dt to both sides, then you get $x \ dx +y \ dy =0$ which is just separable.  If I change the problem into $x'=(x+y)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $y'=(y-x)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ . This time I get $x \frac{dx}{dt}+y \frac{dy}{dt}=(x^2+y^2)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ which I still don't know how to solve, since the dt exists. Thus I think probably the polar coordinate transformation is a very useful way. Can you also explain this a little bit? Thank you!

Comment: @Yinky if you substitute for $\frac{dx}{dt}$ and $\frac{dy}{dt}$ you will notice a common factor of $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ on both sides, which after you eliminate, becomes $0$ on LHS. This is actually inconsistent because LHS should a constant, $c$ and you have only found one function of the family.

Comment: For polar substitution  look ar  Ninad Munshi's answer @Yinky

Answer (score 2):

## Hint:

Eliminate $dt$ by $\frac{dy}{dt} \div \frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{dy}{dx}$. This is also convenient in removing $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ on RHS. However, note that $\frac{dx}{dt} = 0$ is now to be eliminated from the domain.